# Angular. Build step to remove attribute from html markup

Tags: html, angular, testing, webpack, angular-cli

We use "data-test" attribute in markup to query element in tests. For example:

```
<div data-test='myDiv'></div>
```

We don't want this attribute to be present in the production build. So far I found a workaround to create a directive that in runtime removes attribute for a production build. It's for sure will cost some CPU and seems doubtful. Looking for an approach to remove the attribute in build time. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: How about a script that removes the attributes with regex?

Comment: @riorudo may u please elaborate: removes when and how? 
remove in the source code in the package.json production build script? don't want to care about reverting changes after each build
during compilation time in some webpack build step? would be helpful for a link to a suitable webpack documentation

Comment: You could use a custom webpack builder for that - https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/tree/master/packages/custom-webpack

Comment: @IAfanasov I'm looking for the same thing.. unfortunately I cannot find anything :/ did you manage to solve this in your application?

Comment: nope. looks like a custom webpack plugin could do it. if you manage to do it, would thankful for sharing it (:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this article on how to remove `data-cy` attributes during compilation (using webpack loader) or runtime (using directive). You can do exact the same steps for any `data-*` attribute (and ignore the Cypress stuff). Just replace the `data-cy` expression with `data-test` and you are done.

https://medium.com/agilix/angular-and-cypress-data-cy-attributes-d698c01df062

This works at least for Angular6+.